# Grab link on hover - Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I want to grab the underlying link address on mouse hover.

Even if I can grab the link shown in my statusbar it would be enough.

This is for a firefox addon that I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mouseOver(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.href);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few easy steps

1. Get all links on page
2. Subscribe to mouseover event for each link
3. Onmouseover get the url

This would be more straightforward with jQuery, but this gets the job done.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('mouseover',getLink,false)
    //for less than ie9 use attachEvent (figure it out yourself)
}


function getLink() {
    alert(this.href);
}
```